How to check if the passed reference is an instance of a particular ViewChild Reference in Angular
I have a viewchild ref in my .ts file like,
@ViewChild('someDialog') someDialog: ElementRef;

and in the .html file, I'm passing the reference back to a function like,
<abc-dialog #someDialog (close)="onDialogClose(someDialog)"></abc-dialog>

In my .ts file I want to check whether the passed reference to the onDialogClose() function is equal to someDialog view child ref.
Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.

Change your ViewChild to look for the component.
The read property gets the DI token you provide, here it is the component itself, so it will have the component reference.
@ViewChild('someDialog', { read: AbcDialogComponent }) someDialog: AbcDialogComponent;

or
The ViewChild gets the DI token you provide, here it is the component itself, so it will have the component reference.
@ViewChild(AbcDialogComponent) someDialog: AbcDialogComponent;


It's not necessary use "exportAs" nor #someDialog="AbcDialogComponent", just in ViewChild {read:AbcDialogComponent}. The use of ExportAs is related to when we have a component with one directive. BTW inside the .html, the template reference is always the component

@Eliseo with exportAs use can directly pass the component reference to the function. that is why I suggested it

when you pass from .html the reference is always of type the "component" (or an HTMLElement  if it's not a component). Unless you have, e.g. a component and a directive , or two directive in the same "tag" it's not necessary)

@Eliseo Yes, you're right, my mistake sorry
